# Questions related to open intervals and open sets

Tags: real-analysis

Decide on the validity of the following conjectures
a) Continuous functions take bounded open intervals to bounded open intervals.

I can pick a counter example f(x) = tan(x) which is bounded -2 < x < 2 but f(x) is unbounded

b) Continuous functions take bounded open intervals to open sets.
For this question, what is the difference between open intervals and open sets?

Comment: There's a simple example of a continuous function which maps an open interval to a closed interval...

Comment: a flat line without two end points will do it right?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)=C$ also works.  I was thinking $f(x) = \sin x$: maps $(0,2\pi)$ to $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Open sets are arbitrary unions and finite intersection of open intervals. For example $(0,1)\cup (2,5)$ is an open set, but it is not an interval.

Comment: Also the unbounded sets written $(-\infty,x)$ and $(y,\infty)$.

Comment: is (0,1) U {5} an open set?

Comment: And by the way, the statement is not true.

Comment: No. ${5}$ has no neighbourhood $N$ around it such that $N$ is completely contained in $(0,1)\cup \{5\}$.

Comment: @aschepler 4 These cases are taken care of by the arbitrary unions.